# Программно задать масштаб при открытии Excel

Tags: delphi-7

У меня такая ситуация -  нажимая кнопку открывается  `excel`  и масштаб автоматически 100%, а я хочу чтобы было по другому.
Я тут код нашёл, но не получается его применить. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
ExcelApp.PageSetup.Zoom := False;
ExcelApp.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide :=  1;
ExcelApp.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall :=  1;
ExcelApp.PageSetup.Zoom :=  70;
```

Comment: PageSetup - это масштаб для печати. Ищите другое свойство Zoom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Zoom:=85;
```

все получилось))

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код для делфи, который у меня сработал

```
WorkBook.Sheets[1].PageSetup.Zoom:=80;
```